# Firefox gives an error with a CSP policy that shouldn't happen

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, content-security-policy

A firefox addon with the following csp in the sidebar html document: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src *;">`

Gives this error with a `<style></style>` embedded in the same html document of that policy

Error:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
> resource at inline (“style-src”).

I get the same error with "style-src 'self';" or "default-src *;" or etc, it only works when i dont use default-src or style-src

This shouldn't happen so please tell me if i missed something

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'self'` and `*` allow external sources only (ie `<link href='https://example.com' rel='stylesheet'>`).
To allow inline styles requires `'unsafe-inline'` or `'nonce-value'` token. For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'nonce-abcFe45';">
```

and in the HTML:

```
<style nonce="abcFe45">
...
</style>
```

Or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'unsafe-inline';">` will allow any inline `<style></style>` blocks and `<tag style='color:red'>` too.